# How does React 18 impact react testing library rendering?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

My application has an extensive test suite using react-testing-library and jest. The full test suite was passing when the application was using React 17. After I upgraded it to React 18, 49 tests failed. I upgraded to the latest versions of react-testing-library/react, react-testing-library/jest-dom, and react-testing-library/user-event to see if that would fix things, but it did not.

Most tests are seemingly failing because some text should be on the screen after an API call is made, but the text never appears. I've used `waitFor(() => expect(api).toHaveBeenCalled()` to ensure the API has been called and then `findByText` to wait for the text to appear. When I actually run my application, the text is there. So I know the code functionally works, but the test should be pass, too!

Is there something I should know about how and when React 18 renders elements to help me update my tests to pass? What else might be causing these tests to suddenly fail?

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise to post some code as an example. Your question is almost entirely theoretical at this point.

Comment: It can be related to `useEffect` running twice in react 18

Answer (score -1):

You could take the following steps, so that the tests pass in react 18 (I also faced the issue of test failures after upgrading from react 17 to 18):

1. As Konrad has mentioned in the comments that it could be related to `useEffect` running twice. So, you should disable strict mode on dev server and then try running the tests. Disabling strict mode will cause useEffect to stop executing twice.
2. Upgrade your RTL to latest version.
3. Try using await findBy instead of getBY if getBy is throwing an exception due to being unable to find the element.

Comment: I'm not sure the useEffect is the cause. But not only did I have to wrap any API calls in waitFor, but I also had to wrap at least one of the UI changes that occurs due to the API response in the same waitFor block.

Comment: waitFor function is used to wait for a certain condition to meet the expectation. If the expectation is not met, it retries the condition until the expectation is met or a timeout has occurred. I don't know which API call you wrapped inside the waitFor. However, I think passing API call to waitFor may not be the correct solution. Further reading: https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/#waitfor
Furthermore, I said in the original answer that 'replace waitFor by act'. It is wrong. Both functions have different purposes. So I have edited the answer now.